# SQL: Regular Expressions `

Tags: sql, regex

I need to have a sql rexeg pattern that matches any number between 42.67 and 42.86

This is what i Have, but I am not sure if its working

```
42\.[6-9][0-6]
```

Can anyone help ? Thanks !!

I am using an analytics program that only accepts sql regex i do not have access to the db to run queries against it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
42\.(6[7-9]|7[0-9]|8[0-6])
```

Comment: Much simpler than what I suggested!

Comment: Thank you so much, that is spot on.`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a regex?  Just select column from table where column>=42.67 and column<=42.86;

Comment: because i am using an analytics program that only accepts sql regex i do not have access to the db to run queries against it

Comment: Ugggh...in that case, what you have won't work, as 42.90 would match.  Instead, try something like /42\.((67)|(68)|...|(86))/ (where the rest of the digit possibilities would go inside the "...".

Comment: @Kev. Perhaps you should include that bit in your question. If the analytics program is a commercial product you might also want to consider adding that to your question.